# Jenkins pipeline making docker image using img, throwing `nsenter: USER is unset: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Tags: image, jenkins

Im trying build the docker image using [img](https://github.com/genuinetools/img), im able to install the img in jenkins, but when i try to make the image using make file showing

> nsenter: USER is unset: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Below is the cmd to install the img

```
 sudo apt-get update -y \\
                        && sudo apt-get install -y uidmap \\
                        && echo "Downloading img" \\
                        && curl -fSL "https://github.com/genuinetools/img/releases/download/v0.5.11/img-linux-amd64" -o "/usr/local/bin/img" \\
                        && echo "cc9bf08794353ef57b400d32cd1065765253166b0a09fba360d927cfbd158088  /usr/local/bin/img" | sha256sum -c - \\
                        && chmod a+x "/usr/local/bin/img"
```